# jQuery fade jumping to the top of a page

Tags: jquery, fade

I have a basic reveal using jquery and fade.  It works great except when there is content above it jumps to the top of the page whenever one of the links is clicked

```
  $(".link").click(function() {
      $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
      $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wqc9N/8/

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use prevent default

```
  $(".link").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
      $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
  });
```

[here is a DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Wqc9N/10/)

Comment: Perfect answers from all!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `javascript:void(0)` instead of `#` for the `href` of your `<a>`...

[**<kbd>JSFiddle Demo</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/TXY47/)

Answer (score 1):

Since the links are wrapped in a tags you have to prevent the default behavior of the tag.
Try:

```
$(".link").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
  $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
});
```